# Why does "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" happend and how to solve it?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

I'm currently learning ML from tensorflow series. In this case is about text classification. As you can see in the code, I already trained the model and save it as a file to test it.

**Loading the saved file**

```py
modelFile = keras.models.load_model('model_text_classification.h5')
```

**Function to encode:**

```py
def review_encode(string):
  '''look up the mapping of all the words and return to us an encoded list'''

  encoded = [1] # start with 1 as a starting tag as the system with word_index['<START>'] = 1

  for word in string:
    if word in word_index:
      encoded.append(word_index[word.lower()])
    else:
      encoded.append(2) # as the END tag

  return encoded
```

**Pre-processing:**

1. the file is a large string, but I need to convert this into an encoded list of numbers
2. the size of the text is only at max 256 words, because that's how I was using when I trained the data

```py
with open('lion_king.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    nline = line.replace(',', '').replace('.', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('\"', '').replace(':', '')
    nline = nline.split(' ')

    # encode and trim the data down to 256 words
    encode = review_encode(nline)
    encode = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences([encode], value = word_index['<PAD>'], padding = 'post', maxlen = 256) # [encode], because is expecting a list of lists

    # using the model to make a prediction
    predict = model.predict_classes(encode)

    print(line)
    print(encode)
    print(predict(encode[0])) #HERE IS ERROR
```

**Expecting output:**
print the prediction as 96% positive.
*example:* [0.9655667]

**The full traceback:**

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-790c338a89ce> in <module>()
     13     print(line)
     14     print(encode)
---> 15     print(predict(encode[0]))

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: What were you expecting `predict(encode[0])` to do? Is there some `predict` function you were hoping to call? (If so, you shouldn't have reused the `predict` name for `predict(encode[0])`.) Or are you unsure how to access the data in the prediction results you computed?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica predict is a function in keras that return the scores of the regression. In this case, the prediction of a movie review (round 96% positive). For example:  [0.9655667]

Comment: Then you shouldn't have reused the name for `predict = model.predict_classes(encode)`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I think it doens't work like that. Data instances in the numpy array called encode can be passed to the predict_classes() function on the model in order to predict the class values for each instance in the array. I can change it to whatever is the name, but still will give me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `predict = model.predict_classes(encode)` which overwrites any function definition of predict and replace with an array.

So Predict is an array which is not callable.
If you just to see the predicted class for `encode[0]` you can use: `print(predict[0])`